# proceed to another function only if the other function is finished iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

In My iOS App i want to make sure only if current location updated do the other function.

my ViewDidAppear function calls the Location retriving method

```
self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
      self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
                self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    //Following method should call only after location updated
    self.mainFunction()
```

but when app is launching for the first time it dosent work sometimes. sometimes i get the result the other time not.

Comment: `startUpdatingLocation` is do background process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do something like this. add `locationUpdated` Boolean variable to locationManager. if location updated variable gets true. then only `loadData` gets called

```
 func locationtimer(){
        if(locationUpdated){
            self.loadData()
            println("This is called")
        }else{
         var Timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("locationtimer"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        println("Function Working")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`CLLocationManager` updates location asynchronously. Which means that it will call the appropriate method of its delegate when new location is found.

So, you need to:

1) Set the delegate for you `CLLocationManager` (for example to the view controller from which you call `startUpdatingLocation`

```
self.locationManager.delegate = self
```

2) Ensure that your view controller declares conformance to `CLLocationManagerDelegate` protocol:

```
class yourViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate
```

3) Implement the function below

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let location = locations.last {
        // new location is found. You can now call the function which will update your UI to reflect that new location is found
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this. only problem is sometimes function call multiple times inside that function

Comment: You need to call self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation when you are finished. Otherwise your manager will be updating location constantly

Answer (score 0):

"didUpdateLocations" might be the function you need:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didUpdateLocations:

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should called `CLLocationManagerDelegate` location delegate method.

```
self.yourLocationManagerObject.delegate = self
```